# How to use Google AMP Cache for my AMP Website

Tags: caching, browser-cache, amp-html

How to use or setup a google AMP cache for my amp website. I have seen many site manages their request from google.com server . How it is possible for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Google serve your pages as AMP-page, the page must be re-written / modified to make it fit the AMP requirements.

AMP-pages are stripped down versions of web pages, with some restrictions compared to ordinary websites. The HTML markup is slightly different, i.e. and there are other restrictions such as CSS limited to 100kb. Those sites are separately hosted and as soon as Google crawled it, it might be included in the AMP mobile search results.

See [AMP documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/) for the details on how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks wenzf..i have followed the documentation and there is no error in my website. But i can't understand how my website will be hosted from google server.

Comment: @MubashirRahman How the AMP-pages are hosted from Google? In the non-AMP HTML page you put a link tag that refers to the AMP page, i.e. <link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">. This way Google becomes aware of the AMP-page when it crawls the non-AMP-page. When Google decides to include the AMP-page in the search results, Google loads the page in its cache from where it's served.
See [also](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/create/prepare_for_discovery/?format=websites)